# Uploading to Google Play Different Fingerprints

Tags: android, google-play, key, fingerprinting

I created a key.jks file using the keytool, followed the instructions carefully from https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android and yet the error below repeats. Any ideas?

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: D9:98:AB:A9:49:61:72:CE:FF:EA:77:7C:10:6D:1A:DF:34:B8:F5:5B ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: A8:0D:00:CF:1A:00:11:6A:04:A0:7C:0F:FD:DF:BA:ED:55:26:27:C8 ]

Comment: Having watched videos I tried again with a new key file and appbundle, the result: 

Upload failed
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: D9:98:AB:A9:49:61:72:CE:FF:EA:77:7C:10:6D:1A:DF:34:B8:F5:5B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware, as I uploaded an app in 2013 and downloaded it myself support could not delete the app, hence I created a new Google email account and paid again and uploaded it with a new key. This worked. So hold on to your key or pay again.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error bacause of upload key is defferent. Whenever you create a app on Google Play and upload first(signed) build of your app that become your upload key your .jks file that get used to singed that build is your upload key try to push update with same key or if you lost it try contacting Google from play console they will help you in resetting your upload key

Comment: Thanks so much, many years ago I did load up an app, so that's why it doesn't take the new key, so I have now contacting the support as I have the developer code, thanks so much.

Comment: Beware, as I uploaded an app in 2013 and downloaded it myself support could not delete the app, hence I created a new Google email account and paid again and uploaded it with a new key. This worked. So hold on to your key or pay again.

Comment: I think you won't have to get a new Google play console account because if you have access to your old account you can create new app or ask Google console team to rest your upload key 